# How to get custom characters from very large string in PHP

Tags: php, string, associative-array

I have a string of currencies - currency code, name and rates (first rate is units per EUR and second is EUR per unit).

```
string(6429) "                                USD     US Dollar       1,164342        0,858854        
EUR     Euro1,000000 1,000000        GBP     British Pound   0,842392        1,187096        
INR     Indian Rupee    87,128927       0,011477        AUD     Australian Dollar    1,549853        0,645222        CAD     Canadian Dollar 1,435142        0,696795        SGD     Singapore Dollar        1,564234        0,639291    CHF      Swiss Franc     1,070921        0,933776        MYR     Malaysian Ringgit       4,846357        0,206341        JPY     Japanese Yen    132,999525  0,007519 CNY     Chinese Yuan Renminbi   7,444264        0,134332        NZD     New Zealand Dollar      1,616910        0,618464        THB     Thai Baht   38,890927        0,025713        HUF     Hungarian Forint        362,270767      0,002760        AED     Emirati Dirham  4,276047        0,233861        HKD Hong Kong Dollar 9,052195        0,110470        MXN     Mexican Peso    23,485298       0,042580        ZAR     South African Rand      16,811235       0,059484     PHP     Philippine Peso 59,132446       0,016911
```

and so on...
IMPORTANT - This is copy/paste string so whitespace count is like in example and it can be random between integers and words.
String is in one line without line breaks.

So my goal here is to get currency code and currency rate "unit per EUR" (first value)

Preferable output associative array.

Example:

```
$pairs = [
    'USD' => 1,164342,
    'GBP' => 0,842392,
];
```

and so on for every currency.

I can't use any API.

Can anyone help me with this task?

Update: Piece of original string with line breaks

```
string(6667) "ValÅ«tas kods   ValÅ«tas nosaukums      VienÄ«bas par EUR       EUR par vienÄ«bu        
USD     US Dollar       1,164342        0,858854        
EUR     Euro    1,000000        1,000000        
GBP     British Pound   0,842392        1,187096        
INR     Indian Rupee    87,128927       0,011477        
AUD     Australian Dollar       1,549853        0,645222        
CAD     Canadian Dollar 1,435142        0,696795        
SGD     Singapore Dollar        1,564234        0,639291        
CHF     Swiss Franc     1,070921        0,933776        
MYR     Malaysian Ringgit       4,846357        0,206341        
JPY     Japanese Yen    132,999525      0,007519        
CNY     Chinese Yuan 
Renminbi        7,444264        0,134332        
NZD     New Zealand Dollar      1,616910        0,618464
```

Comment: Are there linebreaks or is everything in one line ?

Comment: @WilliPasternak i allready removed linebreaks so this string is in one line.

Comment: can you post a part of the original file

Comment: @WilliPasternak updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is something that you need. Check it please

```
    $string = "                                USD     US Dollar       1,164342        0,858854        
EUR     Euro1,000000 1,000000        GBP     British Pound   0,842392        1,187096        
INR     Indian Rupee    87,128927       0,011477        AUD     Australian Dollar    1,549853        0,645222        CAD     Canadian Dollar 1,435142        0,696795        SGD     Singapore Dollar        1,564234        0,639291    CHF      Swiss Franc     1,070921        0,933776        MYR     Malaysian Ringgit       4,846357        0,206341        JPY     Japanese Yen    132,999525  0,007519 CNY     Chinese Yuan Renminbi   7,444264        0,134332        NZD     New Zealand Dollar      1,616910        0,618464        THB     Thai Baht   38,890927        0,025713        HUF     Hungarian Forint        362,270767      0,002760        AED     Emirati Dirham  4,276047        0,233861        HKD Hong Kong Dollar 9,052195        0,110470        MXN     Mexican Peso    23,485298       0,042580        ZAR     South African Rand      16,811235       0,059484     PHP     Philippine Peso 59,132446       0,016911        ";


preg_match_all('/(USD|GBP)[^\d]*(\d*,?\d*)/', $string, $output);

if ($output) {
    var_dump(array_combine($output[1], $output[2]));
}
```

Just change list of currencies if you need something else like only usd and gbp will be USD|GBP and so on

Comment: Looks almost good except cases when float number is greater than 9 before comma - then code gives back integers.  For example the biggest rate could be Venezuelan Bolívar ~215706753896,646000 But i am allready gratefull for your help because i am not very familiar with regex yet :)

Comment: Edited to support what you need

Comment: Thank you very much @Roman Krut !!!

Comment: Glad to help you